# How to instantiate a Moor_Flutter databse (daos) with provider in main page?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, initialization, flutter-moor

This happens when instantiating the NotificationsPage routed from the MyHomePage()

**Here is my code :**

```
void main() =>runApp(MyApp());



class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final db = AppDatabase();
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // ignore: unnecessary_statements, missing_return
        Provider<MeetingDao>( create: (BuildContext context) {builder: (_) => db.Table1Dao;}, ),
        // ignore: unnecessary_statements, missing_return
        Provider<UserDao>( create: (BuildContext context) {builder: (_) => db.Table2Dao;}, ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is the error log:**

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this NotificationsPage Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that NotificationsPage is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediatly.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

Any suggestion on whats wrong with this main page ? in the Notifications Page I am accessing it like

```
final tbl1Dao = Provider.of<Table1Dao>(context,listen: false);
```